# How can I get 2 children identical components state to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React and I'm trying to get 2 different state from 2 same components ()

```
//parent component
    updateData = (value) => {
        this.setState({ name: value })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="date-picker-container">
                <form>
                    <div className="row">
                        <CalendarInput id="vacationStart" updateData={this.updateData} placeholder="Начало сезона" />
                        <CalendarInput id="vacationEnd" updateData={this.updateData} placeholder="Окончание сезона" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

//And then in child component (<CalendarInput />) I'm calling my updateData function
onClick={() => {this.props.updateData('hello world');}}
```

Comment: Have different functions for each child or provide some identifying data while calling `updateData`

Comment: you need to associate state with the id

Comment: Hey Victor,

It would be really helpful if you provide more details like: expected vs actual behaviour. 

From the code, I don't see anything wrong except that if you click on the first CalendarInput, the state of the parent will update with that input, and when you click on the second CalendarInput, the state of the parent will be "replaced". If this is by design, then I don't see what's wrong. Otherwise, you probably need to expand your parent state to accept multiple states rather than have it overwrite what you already have.

Comment: I got it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

```
//parent component
updateData = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
};
//No need of id

render() {
    return (
        <div className="date-picker-container">
            <form>
                <div className="row">
                    <CalendarInput  updateData={(value) => {this.updateData('vacationStart', value)}} placeholder="Начало сезона" />
                    <CalendarInput  updateData={(value) => {this.updateData('vacationEnd', value)}} placeholder="Окончание сезона" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding your id and value while passing the onClick handler inside the parent component to the child component.

```
    //parent component
    updateData = (id, value) => {
        id === 'vacationStart' ?
        this.setState({ name: value }) :
        this.setState({ name: value })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="date-picker-container">
                <form>
                    <div className="row">
                        <CalendarInput id="vacationStart" updateData={this.updateData('vacationStart', 'Hello World')} placeholder="Начало сезона" />
                        <CalendarInput id="vacationEnd" updateData={this.updateData('vacationEnd', 'Hello new World')} placeholder="Окончание сезона" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
    //Child component
    onClick={this.props.updateData}
```